# how can i get path vocabulary based taxonomy term with node title using views?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have created vocabulary called **Category** and it contains below hierarchy

```
term1 
  term 1.1
     term 1.1.1
     term 1.1.2
     term 1.1.3
  term 1.2
term2
```

and i have assigned to this **category** to content type called **Product** after that i have displayed those product items based on category using views with panels it's working fine.when i click product title the url goes like this

http://www.example.com/content/prodcut-title

but i want path like this

http://www.example.com/category/term1/term1.1/term1.1.1/product-title
category with term based product title using views.

Please suggest possible ways,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change alias pattern for products. Install Entity Token + Pathauto, and on Pattern tab in alias settings (admin/config/search/path/patterns) try to use something like:

```
[node:field-category:parents:join:/]/[node:field-category:name]/[node:title]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick replay@smile.i have tried  following pattern from my site available tokens **"[node:field-categories:1:parents:join:/]/[node:field-categories:1:name]/[node:title]"** but no change when i clk product title.also i have separate template files also other then pattern is there any hardcode one "<?php echo $fields['title']->content; ?>"